# Finding Transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Give a formula for the linear transformation $T: P_2 \rightarrow P_2$ with $T(1) = x^2$, $T(1 + x) = x^2 - 1$, $T(1 + x +x^2) = 2x^2 - 1$ What is the kernel of $T$?

So, if I'm getting this right, the two bases are:

$$B = \{1,x,x^2\}$$ and $$B' = \{1,x,x^2\}$$

So

$$[T(1)]_{B'} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$[T(1 + x)]_{B'} = \begin{bmatrix} -1\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$[T(1 + x + x^2)]_{B'} = \begin{bmatrix} -1\\0\\2 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$[T]_{B',B} = \begin{bmatrix} 0&-1&-1\\0&0&0\\1&1&2\end{bmatrix}$$

I'm not sure how to get the Kernel, but is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$T(x) = T(1+x) - T(1) = x^2-1-x^2 = -1 $$
and
$$T(x^2) = T(1+x+x^2) - T(1+x) = 2x^2 - 1 -(x^2-1) = x^2, $$
so
$$T(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2) = a_0T(1) + a_1T(x) + a_2T(x^2) = -a_1 + (a_0+a_2)x^2.  $$
It follows that the kernel of $T$ is
$$\{a_0+a_2x^2: a_0+a_2=0\}.  $$